# Python Google Drive API not listing all files in folder

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

One part of a program I am writing requires me to list the files and folders within a Google Drive folder. I am currently using the following code:

```
page_token = None
while True:
    response = service.files().list(pageSize=1000,q="'folder_id' in parents",fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

For some reason, one folder that I am testing returns only one file, even if I add additional files/folders, and every other parent folder_id I try results in no files being returned. I even tried deleting the one file that is being returned, and it still gets returned when I call the function again.

Comment: Share a bit more about your environment. Who is this code running as, you? A service account? What shows up in the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?fields=files(description%252CfileExtension%252Cid%252Cname%252Cparents)) for that particular folder? Why not use the [pagination structure](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/pagination) that is recommended for the Google API Python client?

Comment: Are you sure `q="'folder_id' in parents"` is correct?

Comment: your code looks OK. You should add "trashed=false" to the query to prevent your last point about a deleted file still appearing in the results

Answer (score 1):

If your are using service account which represent a service then:

1. enable domain wide delegation for the service account. steps are and additional [info](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) here.
2. After enabling domain wide delegation ,share the desired folders which you want to list using your service/webapp with service account's email address [Service account link](https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts), it would be something like "XXX...XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com".

Comment: If you share the folder with the service account, I don't think you need domain-wide delegation

Answer (score 1):

1. check if service account have the permission to read the folders
2. if folder is in shared drive add `includeItemsFromAllDrives=True` and `supportsAllDrives=True` to the parameter of list method

```py
response = service.files().list(pageSize=1000,q="'folder_id' in parents",fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",includeItemsFromAllDrives=True, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```

you can read more details [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: This was the trick for me - include these permissions if you have a shared drive